# Python Pylearn2 package "ImportError: No module named pylearn2.utils"

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, machine-learning, package

I have recently tried to use pylearn2, a deep machin learning package for Python developed at University of Montreal.
I've just installed it and tried to run a simple example, but it did not work.

I have been using a pc with an Ubuntu 13.10 system, on which I found ipython installed.
I have installed Theano and later pylearn2, by following this webpage instructions:
 http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/

I have also modified the .bashrc file, as suggested

I thought that everything went well, and then I tried this Quick start example:
 http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/tutorial/index.html

I stopped at the first command:

```
 python make_dataset.py
```

My terminal states:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "make_dataset.py", line 14,
>   in

Do you have any ideas on why it is not working?

Do you why these errors occur?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: the 14 line is the first non-commented line of the file. It states

> from pylearn2.utils import serial

Comment: You need to show us the whole traceback, not just part of the first line. It would also help to either paste the code (at least around line 14) for `make_dataset.py`, or provide a direct link to the code you copied and pasted, instead of making us search for it.

Comment: Meanwhile: "Pylearn2 is still undergoing rapid development. Don’t expect a clean road without bumps!" I notice that the "install" instructions don't actually install anything, which means you'll only be able to run by either having your PWD set to the top-level pylearn2 directory (that is, `cd`ing into the tutorials isn't likely to work), or by modifying your `PYTHONPATH` to include that directory. Did you do either of those? Also, after modifying the .bashrc file, did you either `source ~/.bashrc` or create a new shell? If not, editing the file has no effect.

Comment: Hi guys. A knowdledge colleague helped me and we solved this issue. The problem was that using the Numpy package was missin', and I've installed it through the command `sudo apt-get install python-numpy` on my Ubuntu pc. This was not a good idea, because that package version is antiquate. Instead, I should have used `pip install numpy`, and then 'pip install theano` and then `pip install pylearn`. That way, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I can only guess, but my first guess is…

You haven't *actually* installed pylearn2, because if you follow the linked docs to grab the git repo and add a `PYLEARN2_DATA_PATH` variable, nothing gets installed into `site-packages` (or `dist-packages` or anywhere else on `sys.path`).

This means that pylearn2 will only work when you start Python from within the top-level directory of the pylearn2 repo.

So, if you run a script like this:

```
$ cd /path/to/pylearn2
$ cd scripts/tutorials/grbm_smd/
$ python make_dataset.py
```

… it won't actually work.

---

It looks like there *is* a `setup.py` file in the repository. Does it work? I have no idea. Even though the docs don't mention using it, you might want to try. Either this:

```
$ pip install .
```

… or, if you don't have `pip` or it doesn't work on this package:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

Either way, of course, you may need `sudo` or a flag to install to your user site-packages instead of system, etc., as with any other Python package.

If that doesn't work, you might be able to just add `/path/to/pylearn2` to your `sys.path` in some way. The most obvious way is by doing an `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/pylearn2:$PYTHONPATH` in your ~/.bashrc.

---

Also, you will need to either `source ~/.bashrc` or create a new shell to get any effects of modifying the file.

---

If you're wondering why the instructions and the tutorial together don't give you enough information to make this work without a lot of hassle, I think that's covered in the very top of the documentation:

> Pylearn2 is still undergoing rapid development. Don’t expect a clean road without bumps!

And the very fact that there is no PyPI download yet implies that this really is not ready for novices to use. If you don't know enough about using Python packages (and bash basics) to muddle through on your own, there's a good chance you won't be able to use this package.